# Linkedin url Validation - Input field JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a from just simple form there is an input field for Linkedin url. Is there is anyway to validate that field only accepts linkedin url? Thanks

Comment: is there is anway to validate linkedin Regexp in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `JS` you can check if the input value matches a pattern for a LinkedIn URL, Like this demo:

```js
$("#validateurl").click(function(){
  pattern = new RegExp(/(https?)?:?(\/\/)?(([w]{3}||\w\w)\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/);
  if(!pattern.test($("#urlvalue").val())) {
    alert("Url not valid");
  } else {
    alert("Valid url");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="urlvalue" />
<button id="validateurl"> Validate </button>
```

Examples of valid URLs:

```
http://linkedin.com/in/jjjjjj

https://www.linkedin.com/company/somecompany/
```

Examples of not valid URLs:

```
http://test.com

http://www.aaa.com/444
```

Comment: hai, im using php as backend so when i add this code the pattern = new RegExp having some erros like last part getting commented and ther error is 

Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 0 of file Unknown. Please fix and try saving again.

Exception thrown without a stack frame

Comment: also im using a forminator field so can i use this code to that field

Comment: Do you want to check the URL value using jquery or using PHP code, here you tagged jquery and javascript, not PHP. My be if you share more of your code we can understand more how you use your check.

Comment: I fixed it now its working.... THanks for the help it was my side mistake ..

Comment: hai again.. im looking for php regexp for linkedin url validation. jquery is working fine i have to use php regexp for validatoin

Comment: you can check with preg_match function: if(preg_match('/(https?)?:?(\/\/)?(([w]{3}||\w\w)\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/', $yourUrlToCjeck)) { //Valid URL } else { // Not valid URL }

Comment: i did but not working

Comment: add_filter(
 'forminator_custom_form_submit_errors',
 function( $submit_errors, $form_id, $field_data_array ) {
  $field_name = 'text-1';
  $submitted_fields = wp_list_pluck( $field_data_array, 'value', 'name' );
  $pattern = "/(https?)?:?(\/\/)?(([w]{3}||\w\w)\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/";
  if( !preg_match($pattern, $submitted_fields[ $field_name ] ) ) {
   $submit_errors[][ $field_name ] = __( 'Please enter a valid LinkedIn URL' );
  }
  return $submit_errors;
 },
 10, 
 3
);

Comment: It's preferable to add a new question for that so the need will be clear and do not forget to add PHP tag

Answer (score 0):

**Using JS you can check if the input value matches a pattern for a LinkedIn URL.I hope solve your problem:**

```js
$("#BtnCheck").click(function(){
  val = $('#UrlVal').val();
  if( /(ftp|http|https):\/\/?(?:www\.)?linkedin.com(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:([0-9])+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/.test(val) )
  {
   alert( 'valid Linkedin URL' );
  }
  else
  {
   alert( 'not valid Linkedin URL' );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="UrlVal" />
<button id="BtnCheck"> Check </button>
```